# auto-fill not working in InAppBrowserObject external website on Android device

Tags: android, authentication, ionic-framework, autofill, inappbrowser

I have been struggling to get my app working the way I want it to. I have an ionic/angular based app that is meant to be only for the Android platform. It is basically a wrapper for an already-existing website from the company I work at. The InAppBrowserObject works great for this, it does exactly what I want except that it doesn't auto-fill the login credentials. It makes it so users need to login every time they open the app which is not what we want. We want the external website to open in the app itself and not in the device's browser, so I use "_*self"* as target.

I have noticed that when I use the device's browser (target: _*system)* that it asks for permission to save the credentials and then it does actually save them. It is only when I use the targets: "_self" or "_blank" that I get no popup asking to save it (it also doesn't save it). In the image below you can see the code in the app.component.ts file and some information about the app which might be important. The app is small, it literally only has the app.component files and that's it. It opens the external website immediatly when the app is started.

At this point I am clueless as to what to do about this problem. I think I have visited every website that is related to this subject and the solutions are either outdated or there is no solution at all. I hope I gave enough information as to what the problem is, if not, I can always add more.

Information:

- using Angular(ts), Ionic in vs-code. Testing apk in Android Studio.
- InAppBrowserObject (Cordova, @awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser)

[image: app.component.ts file]app.component.ts file ^

[image: login not auto-filling the inputs with _self as target]target set to _self and not auto-filling the inputs (the inputs in the website are set with autocomplete on)

[image: login auto-filling the inputs with _system as target]target set to _system and auto-filling is working correctly.